# image loaded using a servlet always shows a red cross

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have used the following code to create a file in a temp location and save an image in that location, when this page is loaded i always see a red cross " if the older image is deleted or always shows the cached image not the latest image" .

```
 String file_suffix=df.format(new Date());
            File file= new File("/home/martini/Apache/tomcat/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/webapps/dashboard/tmp_imgs/tmp"+file_suffix +".jpeg");
            if(!(file.exists())){
                file.createNewFile();
            }
             p_resp.setContentType("image/jpeg");
                chart = u.genarateLineChart(m_martiniInstance);
                ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(file, chart, 625, 800);

                HTMLHelper.writeHTMLHead(m_out);
                 m_out.println("<body bgcolor=\"#B4A383\"> "
                            + "  <center> "
                            + "  <img src=\"/dashboard/_imgs/sungard_martini.png\" alt=\"SunGard Martini\" border=\"0\" /> "
                            + "  <p><br><br></p>");
                    m_out.println(
                             "  <div align=center>"
                            + "  <img src=\"/dashboard/tmp_imgs/tmp" + file_suffix + ".jpeg\" border=\"0\" /> "
                            +"</div>"
                            + "  <p><br><br></p>");
```

I would like a new file to be created for the image every time and load the new image in a temp file irrespective of a previous image in a temp file being present.
Is there any way of achiveing this because when i see a red cross or a older file i refresh the page and then i see the new image being loaded.

Thanks,

Bhavya

Comment: Can you find the images in your in your filesystem/ftp? Is the relative `src` really the correct path (where is your webapp/the corresponding servlet located)?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you do this to be certain you get a fresh file every time the page is reloaded?

Comment: +1, maybe you need to provide absolute uri instead of relative. Also, consider changing the extension to JPG instead of JPEG.

Comment: @cularis yes i can find the images in the src path @fvu i am doing this to ensure that a new file is loaded every time @Mohamed Nuur i am saving the file with a jpeg extn i think it expects to find a file with jpeg extn else it may fail with an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");` in the beginning of your servlet's doPost()/doGet() method. This should prevent caching.

Other trick is to add some kind of dummy parameter at the end of URL. This can be implemented using javascript at client side. For example your url looks like:

http://myserver/myapp/images/myimage.jpg

change it to

http://myserver/myapp/images/myimage.jpg?dummy=123456

The value of dummy parameter may be timestamp in milliseconds or random number etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of tackling what I am guessing is your goal, ie a guaranteed fresh graph on every reload, might be the following approach:

1. Create a servlet that handles (url-pattern) /dashboard/tmp_imgs/tmp/* (notice the *).
2. Have your present code generate the dummy image url as it does now.  The exact filename is not important, it's just always different to trick the browser into reloading it always.

The image servlet should look more or less like

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    chart = u.genarateLineChart(m_martiniInstance);
    ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(out, chart, 625, 800);
    out.close();
}
```

Not 100% sure of the writeChartAsJPEG call's parameters....

Of course, with the proposed url-pattern the servlet will be called to handle everything in `/dashboard/tmp_imgs/tmp/` so if you're using that path for other, physical files you should change it (in web.xml and in the calling code) to something that's unique.  It doesn't need to be backed by existing files.

Advantages?

- Each servlet handles 1 task, no implicit multitasking behind your back
- No file ever gets written to disk, less clutter and improved performance